# Create an updatable view of a single record from a numpy recarray

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have the following node and element data types, and record array that defines a bunch of nodes:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: node=np.dtype([('x', np.float32), ('y', np.float32)])

In [3]: element=np.dtype([('i', node), ('j', node), ('k', node), ('l', node)])

In [4]: nodes = np.rec.array([(1,2), (3,4)], dtype=node)
```

I can populate a record array of elements (just a single element in this minimal example) like so:

```
In [5]: elements=np.rec.array([(nodes[0], nodes[1], nodes[0], nodes[1])], dtype=element)
```

However if I access the `element[0].i` node and update the node location, the updated location is not reflected in the nodes array:

```
In [6]: elements[0].i = (2,3)

In [7]: nodes[0]
Out[7]: (1., 2.)
```

I understand from the documentation that the proper way to update the information probably has [something to do with using a view on the record](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.record.view.html). I have attempted to create an element record using view on each node record this way, but it doesn't seem to work the way I need it to (looks like it just creates a copy of the record 0, and then a view on that copy):

```
In [8]: elements=np.rec.array([(nodes[0].view(), nodes[1].view(), nodes[0].view(), nodes[1].view())], dtype=element)

In [9]: elements[0].i = (2,3)

In [10]: nodes[0]
Out[10]: (1., 2.)

In [11]: elements[0].i
Out[11]: (2., 3.)
```

How can I create updatable views of individual node records in `elements` so that changes to any single record are reflected in the `nodes` array?

Comment: Not sure this is possible. What you can do is `node_v = nodes[0,...]` and then assign via `node_v[()] = 3,1`. This will change `nodes`, but I do not see a way of putting this kind of thing into another array. Unless perhaps if the array is of object dtype, but then you loose all the recarray niceties. Btw., in your example when you change `elements[0].i` do you want `elements[0].k` to automatically change to the same value?

Comment: @loopywalt i suppose i could still at least use a structured array using an object dtype. but would the underlying values of an object be updated using this kind of assignment? `elements[0]['i']=(2,3)`? Seems like it might not... I guess I'd need to create a method instead, like `elements[0]['i'].update(2,3}`. To answer your question: yes, all references to `nodes[0]` should "see" the change.

Comment: Not with this syntax because the element would be set via assignment i.e. rebinding. You would need to do something like `elements[0]['i'][()] = 2,3` to trigger the element's `__setitem__` method.

Comment: @loopywalt Ok i guess that's not *TERRIBLE*. sure would be nice to figure out a pretty way to wrap all this into something that provides the interface i want... i'll have to think about whether that would be possible without basically reimplementing the entirety of the `recarray` and `record` classes.

Comment: You may or may not get away with overriding `__setitem__` (of the container array).

Comment: @loopywalt thanks! i think i would have to have my own custom `recordview` type, too, though. blurgh. thanks again.

Comment: All the customization for `recarrays` occur in the `np.core.records.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [205]: nodes
Out[205]: 
rec.array([(1., 2.), (3., 4.)],
          dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4')])

In [208]: elements
Out[208]: 
rec.array([((1., 2.), (3., 4.), (1., 2.), (3., 4.))],
          dtype=[('i', [('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4')]), ('j', [('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4')]), ('k', [('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4')]), ('l', [('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4')])])
```

You have nested the dtypes, making a rather complicated one.

```
In [209]: nodes[0]
Out[209]: (1., 2.)

In [212]: elements['i']
Out[212]: 
rec.array([(1., 2.)],
          dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4')])
In [213]: elements['i'][0]
Out[213]: (1., 2.)
```

In creating `elements` from `nodes`, it's copied elements by value, not reference.  There's no `object` dtypes here, just `f4` floats.

`elements` is a (1,) shape array.  One element/record. The concept of `view` applies only to the outer `shape` level.  There's no equivalent within the record.

This is a minor point, but you could use 'plain' structured arrays:

```
In [214]: nodes = np.array([(1,2), (3,4)], dtype=node)
In [215]: nodes
Out[215]: array([(1., 2.), (3., 4.)], dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4')])
```

Structured arrays are more common these days, but the only thing `recarray` adds is the ability to access fields with attribute syntax, `nodes.x` versus `nodes['x']`.

redefining `element` to use object dtypes:

```
In [218]: element=np.dtype([('i', 'O'), ('j', 'O'), ('k', 'O'), ('l', 'O')])
In [219]: elements=np.array([(nodes[0], nodes[1], nodes[0], nodes[1])], dtype=element)
In [220]: elements
Out[220]: 
array([((1., 2.), (3., 4.), (1., 2.), (3., 4.))],
      dtype=[('i', 'O'), ('j', 'O'), ('k', 'O'), ('l', 'O')])
```

changing a subrecord still doesn't changes `nodes`.  It just replaces the original `nodes[0]` object with a tuple (not a record - not the change to ints):

```
In [221]: elements['i'][0] = (10,20)
In [222]: elements
Out[222]: 
array([((10, 20), (3., 4.), (1., 2.), (3., 4.))],
      dtype=[('i', 'O'), ('j', 'O'), ('k', 'O'), ('l', 'O')])
In [223]: nodes
Out[223]: array([(1., 2.), (3., 4.)], dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4')])
```

I was able to change an element of a `nodes` record, and see that change in all the `nodes[1]` elements of `elements`:

```
In [239]: nodes['x'][1]=30
In [240]: nodes
Out[240]: array([( 1., 2.), (30., 4.)], dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4')])
In [241]: elements
Out[241]: 
array([((10, 20), (30., 4.), (1., 2.), (30., 4.))],
      dtype=[('i', 'O'), ('j', 'O'), ('k', 'O'), ('l', 'O')])
```

But changing a whole `node` record in `elements` is proving trickier.  I can't find the right syntax to do this in-place.

I have a feeling that this kind of dtype nesting, even with object dtype, is making this a whole lot more complicated than its worth.  Keep in mind that object dtype arrays are more like lists than numeric arrays.  Sure they have shape and dtype, but all math is done a list-comprehension speeds (if it works at all).  Also structured arrays are great for storing a mix of dtypes, say floats, ints and strings, such as when loading `csv` files.  But they aren't that useful when handling complicated data structures.

Comment: Of course pandas is the goto when you need something more capable than a structured array, but I have not been able to find a way to accomplish any of this with pandas either.